# Is Google not Support .net sites in Search List?

Tags: .net

Hey Friends, Please help me. See, I have created lots of sites in .net from a long time, bz i just know .net and mvc, mvc2. but every time google not support my sites, when i launch google come and got my site pages fastly but after that google just come everyday only my site homepage that's it. I don't know what the reason? is i m doing something wrong. or when google come for read my site, then something wrong? like IIS down or what?

Please help me guys, bz now i m totally frustrate from google or .net? Anyone can help me, just tell me guys, just give me hint that google not support .net or what's the reason? bz from few days i notice that there is no site in .net, So i think may be google not support .net

Comment: SO is built using .NET so it's the best example that your assumption is wrong. Search Google/this site for SEO and see whether your site is good food for indexers.

Comment: make sure that all the pages are decedents of the homepage.

Comment: Why the down vote? A new user and the question is regarding programming.

Comment: I'm sure if you posted the URL here, people would very quickly tell  you what the problem is. Once you get your answer, you could take the site url off.

Comment: @Sunny what happened at the end with this? did you update your code?

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't care if your site is made from .Net fx or your own framework. What it cares are your website contents and your SEO technique. Maybe Google cannot find your websites, maybe Google think your websites are not "interesting" enough so they are burried in million of search results.

if you want proof that Google does "support" .net, try searching "stackoverflow", this site is built using asp.net mvc and it is on Google search result.

Comment: O is good and i have check this from lots of sites like webpagetest.net and other sites too. So i'm sure there is no fault in my SEO. and Google everyday read my site homepage, everyday. I maintain everything as same as google said.

Answer (score 1):

As Ashwini Dhekane has mentioned, your problem is SEO: the ease with which Search Engines can crawl and see your website.

I would suggest that you visit [Google's support page for webmasters](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/) - it tells you how you can architecture your website to be more visible on Google.

Answer (score 1):

> hey Ashwini thanx for the reply, but my SEO is good and i have check this from lots of sites like webpagetest.net and other sites too. So i'm sure there is no fault in my SEO. and Google everyday read my site homepage, everyday. I maintain everything as same as google said.

Stop right there. This is one of the classic development moments we all have lived: it's not my code, what in the world could be happening ... it is your code, nothing special going on. Now with the new finding, revisit the problem and analyze it again.

Classic issue is postback based navigation, change to simple links with query string parameters. I've done this various times for clients, the result is normally from a handful indexed pages to hundreds or thousands depending on the site.

You need to make sure All is accessible with regular links (postback uses js +  post), this is one of the scenarios were progressive enhancement pays off.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is SEO and not .NET or any other framework. Search engine crawls your website according to links on the pages. If some page is not accessible through any link on any web-page in the universe and it is not the homepage then that page is not going to register into google db. Hope this helps.

Comment: hey Ashwini thanx for the reply, but my SEO is good and i have check this from lots of sites like webpagetest.net and other sites too. So i'm sure there is no fault in my SEO. and Google everyday read my site homepage, everyday. I maintain everything as same as google said.

Comment: are you sure that every page is accessible from homepage.